# hidden symbol `pthread_atfork' in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread_nonshared.a(pthread_atfork.oS) is referenced by DSO

Tags: dynamic-linking, static-linking

I am trying to compile a large project, it includes a library:

SAMG/ifort64.9.1.041-emt64/lib/libguide.so

when I try to make project, there is an error message:

```
hidden symbol `pthread_atfork' in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread_nonshared.a(pthread_atfork.oS) is referenced by DSO
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
```

I was trying add -pthreads as well as -lpthreads but it does not help.

Comment: Please add the compiler/link full command line that led to this error, as well as the operating system environment (ubuntu? Which release? etc)